# On Visual Studio 2017 while creating a new C++ project I don't have the options to change the default location as 2015 had

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

This is how it used to look on VS2015 Community:
[image]

This is how it looks on VS2017 Community:
[image]

Also, the wizard is not available anymore and I need to change a few values:
[image]

Comment: I would imagine the full paid version has that functionality.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this, [console application (and other templates) offer selection of project location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN6hI.png). Wizard is still available under name "Windows Desktop Wizard".

Comment: Using the Wizard didn't give the options "Location" and "Solution name", I found the way to create it by choosing an Empty C++ Project instead of a Windows Console application or the Windows Desktop Wizard, then, once I'd created the empty project, I went to Project>Properties>Linker>System>Subsystem and choose the Console option so that it behaves like expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that VS2017 manages this differently, to get the desired options: 
[image]
You need to create an Empty C++ Project instead of a Windows Console application, then, once you've created the empty project, you need to go to Project>Properties>Linker>System>Subsystem and choose the Console option so that it behaves like expected.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that Visual Studio displays prompt for solution location only when `Save new projects when created` option is enabled:

[image]